# Saving jasmine expect() results

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node

Does `expect()` have a return type (or a promise it fulfills)? If not, how can I store/access the result of an `it('should...')`'s `expect()`?

*Edited-Clarification*: I want to store and use these results during subsequent tests.

Reason: I'd like to make some tests resilient enough to know if they should be skipped because prior tests failed, without having to make the comparison a second time and wait for nested promises to all resolve again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/custom_reporter.html which allows you to be notified of the suite/specs success/failure as they are executed.

You could then store this information in an object which could then be accessible to your specs.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to bother making my own reporter. Jasmine claims

> `None of the functions here are required when creating a custom reporter, any that are not specified on your reporter will just be ignored.`

Does this mean it will retain normal Jasmine reporting functionality? Or it will just do nothing for not-given functions?

Comment: Your use case is a bit uncommon, and I'm not aware of another way to dynamically disable specs based of a failure of a previous one. Saying this don't be afraid of the custom reporters, it's very easy to implement them and in fact in your case you only need the `specDone` one.

Comment: I'll bump it lower on my to-do list for now. But when I get to it, I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: sorry didn't notice your questions in your comment. as far as I know it does only add reporters and does not replace the existing ones. I didn't notice any changes in the output of my project using karma, with or without custom reporters.